# Dialogflow Permission denied : IAM permission

Tags: dialogflow-es, permission-denied

I'm just created a new bot and try to make an integration with dialogflow. Yesterday, 2-3 days ago everything was OK.
Today i get this error. Can't find anything similar in internet.
**IAM permission 'dialogflow.agents.get' on 'projects/xxxxxxx-06xx-49xx-xx31-2313x47x2xxx[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGRwk.png)'** (not my real but examle of ID) denied.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exact problem.

The problem is not just in one account, it's happening on all my Dialogflow account.

There is no solution yet.

It's a very annoying problem.

But based on the error message you can try to give a Project owner role to your Dialogflow service account. Maybe it will affect differently for your case.

An additional role for Dialogflow service account:
[image: Additional role for Dialogflow service account]

A similar problem:
[image: A similar problems]

Comment: thanks! I tried but nothing changes. Will try give an owner role one more time and check it out

Answer (score -1):

This issue should be resolved. You can try to start your integrations again to verify.